# Delphi 6 General Update 2 - Error 115

Tags: delphi, ide, installation, delphi-6

I run `D6_upd2_ent.exe` after installing **Borland Delphi 6.0 Enterprise**.

This error has occurred during installation:

[image]

The `dclnet60.bpl` file does not exist in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi6\Bin`.

I downloaded `dclnet60.bpl` from the Internet, copied it to that directory, then run `D6_upd2_ent.exe` again. But the same error occurred with another file.

*(I installed **Borland Delphi 6.0 Enterprise** and `D6_upd2_ent.exe` on another computer, and no error occurred)*

I need a solution to this problem.

Comment: "But the same error occurred with another file." Just curious: why have you not detailed what the other file is?

Comment: Unless you add a permissive ACL to the install directory you will have problems with UAC if you install to program files dir. Many people install to C:\Delphi or similar to avoid having to deal with that.

Comment: @DaveNottage: Here is the list of files to be installed of the **Delphi Update 2** package: http://edn.embarcadero.com/en/article/28405, and **dclnet60.bpl** is also on this list, just like the "another file" that I mentioned above.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Do your mean is install a on a folder other than **Program Files** or **Program Files (x86)** folder? I've reinstalled Delphi on **C: \ Delphi** folder. But the problem is not resolved.

Comment: Did you explicitly start d6_upd2_ent.exe as administrator? Windows tries to be smart about detecting installers, but it will probably fail with this one.

Comment: @dummzeuch: I executed **d6_upd2_ent.exe** with **administrator right**.

Comment: In what sense is your problem "not resolved" if you install to C:\Delphi?

Comment: @MartynA: That mean -> Installing **Borland Delphi 6** on "C:\Delphi" folder does not fix the **Error 115**.

Comment: Have you checked that the installer has not been trying to install anything outside C:\Delphi?  Fwiw, I have installed Delphi **7** Ent on my drive D: several times w/o problems.

Comment: @MartynA: I removed Borland Delphi 6.0 (all installed features) before reinstall it on "C:\Delphi". When I execute **d6_upd2_ent.exe**, **Error 115** still occurence.

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but still: did you try to reboot and then to install?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Yes, I used to do that.

Comment: What is the version of Windows that you use? BTW: The software you are trying to install is from 2001, are you a kind of archeologist or you have a solid reason to choose that particular version of Delphi?

Comment: @zdzichs: I'm using Windows 7 x64 Enterprise. I installed Borland Delphi 6 Update 2 successfully on Windows 10, and I want to try it on other platforms, including Windows 7.

Comment: I believe that it is possible to install D6 on Win10, but I cannot see the reason to use such an old software nowadays. Just buy the licence for the newest Tokyo version and you will even get the licence for D7 included. You can also use Delphi Tokyo Community Edition, which is free (with restrictions) and contains all the Pro features. If you really have to use D6 for compatibility or legal reasons, a VM should be enough.

Comment: @zdzichs: Yes, this is a difficult problem, but i am trying to solve it.